# PHP: Присвоить полю определенное значение на лету при SQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть интернет-магазин. Беру с одной таблицы MySQL айди номера товаров определенной категории имея айди категории, потом имея айди товаров беру их цены с другой таблицы используя LEFT JOIN и сортирую через ORDER BY по полю цена т.е:

```
SELECT a.product_id, b.product_price FROM table_product_categories as a WHERE category_id = $category_id
LEFT JOIN table_product_prices as b ON b.product_id = a.product_id
ORDER BY b.product_price
```

На первый взгляд все просто но с ценой бывают **ДВЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ**:

**1.** Некоторые товары в категории не имеют цены т.е. в таблице `table_product_prices` для их айди номеров нету соответственной записи с ценой. А некоторые цены равны `0` или чуть больше нуля но меньше `1` например `0.01`. В этих случаях такие товары на странице не выводятся вообще.

**2.** Поле `product_price` это первоначальня цена. Вторая проблема заключается в том что для некоторых товаров указана еще "новая" цена в поле `product_override_price` в той же таблице `table_product_prices` (`product_price` в таком случае выступает в качестве "старой" цены), а еще для некоторых товаров указана скидка в поле `product_discount` (в той же таблице). В таких случаях сортировка `ORDER BY b.product_price` неправильна поскольку осуществляется по полю первоначальной цены `product_price` не учитывая ни `product_override_price`, ни `product_discount`. Нам нужно сортировать по окончательной цене, а она рассчитывается на лету и поля под нее в таблице нету.

**КАК ВСЕ ДОЛЖНО РАБОТАТЬ**

**Для решения проблемы 1:** если товар не имеет цены, или же цена равно `0`, или больше `0` но меньше `1` тогда нужно как то на лету в SQL-запросе (если такое возможно) присвоить полю `product_price` значение `1`

**Для решения проблемы 2:** чтобы учитывало новую цену и скидку берем дополнительно с таблицы `table_product_prices` еще поля `b.product_override_price` и `b.product_discount` а дальше если значение поля `b.product_override_price` больше `0` (по умолчанию оно равно 0) тогда сортируем по нему вместо `product_price`, а если значение поля `product_discount` для какого то товара тоже больше `0` например `5` (это значит скидка `5%`) тогда от первоначальной цены `product_price` отнимаем скидку точнее умножаем на `0.05` (*5%).

Возможно нам нужно в SQL-запросе создать на лету какое то "временное" поле типа `final_price` (если такое возможно) и тогда в случае первой проблемы присваивать ему значение `1`, а в случае второй рассчитывать окончательную цену и тогда сортировать через `ORDER BY final_price`

Comment: А есть что-то что пытались сделать?)) И может хоть небольшую часть данных положить в http://sqlfiddle.com/  чтоб было с чем экспериментировать. Так-то с налету можно написать запрос, только не всегда это получится корректно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, запрос должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
SELECT a.`product_id`,
(CASE
    WHEN b.`product_override_price` > 0 THEN b.`product_override_price`
    WHEN b.`product_discount` > 0 THEN  b.`product_price` - (b.`product_discount` * b.`product_price` / 100)
    WHEN b.`product_price` < 1 THEN 1
    ELSE b.`product_price`
END) AS final_price
    FROM `table_product_categories` as a
    LEFT JOIN `table_product_prices` as b ON b.`product_id` = a.`product_id`
    WHERE `category_id` = $category_id
ORDER BY final_price
```

**UPD:** Проверил этот запрос на тестовой базе - работает. Ссылка на рабочий пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aebc0dd/19/0